Creating a Robot Navigation Landscape from Vision and Motion
I have a robot that moves randomly around an apartment using two wheels. Each wheel can be powered independently: applying the same power to both wheels makes the robot move forward, while applying the same power in reverse makes it move backward.
As the robot moves, it captures 32x32 RGB images of its surroundings. For each image, I also have a record of the action taken—the left and right wheel speeds—that led to that particular image.
What I’m aiming for is to create a representation of the apartment as a continuous, unified "landscape." In this landscape, each motion (described by the left and right wheel speeds) would lead to a specific point, represented by an image or some equivalent feature. This would allow the robot to navigate intentionally to a particular spot in the apartment by moving toward the corresponding point in the landscape.
I’ve gathered nearly 100,000 records of the robot’s movements and corresponding images, along with the image features extracted from them. Now, I want to use this data to help the robot navigate its environment in a purposeful, directed way, so it can reach a desired image or location.
